# Angularjs $routeProvider service not working with view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple angularjs application to implement $routeProvider service.
In my index.html page I provided a `div` with `ngView` directive as `<div ng-view></div>` which would display contents of `login.html` page in `/pages` directory.

I followed tutorial on [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/) on angularjs site. But I don't understand why it is still not working.

Here is my directory structure:

```
/Writer (App Folder)
---/js
------app.js
------controllers.js
---/pages
------login.html
---index.html
```

I am providing code of my controllers and html pages. Please take a look and point out if any flaw.

**index.html:**

```html
<html ng-app="Writer">
<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="2.0.0-alpha.45" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**:

```js
angular.module('Writer', ['AllControllers','ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/Diary',{
            templateUrl:'pages/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginFormController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo : '/Diary'});
    }]);
```

**controllers.js**:

```js
var app  = angular.module('AllControllers',[]);

    app.controller('LoginFormController',['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.whichForm = 1;
        
        $scope.setForm = function(formId){
           $scope.whichForm = formId;
        };
        
        $scope.isSetForm = function(formId){
            return $scope.whichForm===formId;
        }
    });
```

**login.html**:

```html
<div class="loginForms">
        <div class="login" ng-show="isSetForm(1)">
            <form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username"/></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password"/></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td><span>Or</span></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Register" value="Register" ng-click="setForm(2)"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <div class="register" ng-show="isSetForm(2)">
             <form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email"/></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="password" name="confirmpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="confirmPass"/></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Register" value="Register" /></td>
                    </tr>
                   <tr><td><span>Or</span></td></tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="Login" value="Already Registered?" ng-click="setForm(1)"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

*Please note I am calling the functions defined in `controllers.js` with `$scope` service, in `login.html` directly as:

```
 <div class="login" ng-show="isSetForm(1)">
```

. Is this approach wrong?

Sorry for a long post but if you could help I'll be very grateful as I am just beginning with angularjs.

Comment: You have an undefined varialbe allStories inside controller.js didn't you have any errors in console?

Comment: @csharpfolk: No there are no errors in console. the index.html page displays nothing.

Comment: What about allStories variable?

Comment: I have updated the controllers.js and removed that. Please check again.

Comment: where is setForm called?

Comment: try to call setForm(1) in you controller

Comment: setForm() function is defined in controllers.js only. And being called in login.html on ng-click

Comment: in broser address bar do you have `#/diary` after app launch

Comment: No. It is just `http://localhost:9090/Writer/`

Comment: And I am running my application on Tomcat server. Just so you know.

Comment: Then it looks like angular doesn't even load. Can you use `angular` variable in console?

Comment: angular variable in console? I don't know how to as I am new to it.

Comment: Chrom -> press F12 -> Console tab. Write angular press enter and see if ReferenceError occur

Comment: @csharpfolk: Yes now it is displaying url as `http://localhost:9090/Writer/#/Diary` but still no data from login.html

Comment: Try to add some `console.log('foo');` calls to your controller they will be displayed in chrome console. maybe this will help you...

Comment: controller is successfully displaying `console.log('foo')` method in console.

Comment: Can't help you, you may try to remove ng-show attribute and check if anything happens.

Comment: @csharpfolk: hey It worked by removing `ng-show` and `ng-click` directives. Any idea why it worked so and not with them?

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki The tutorial is for angular 1.* and you're using angular 2.0 - Try using angular 1.5

Comment: Thanx a lot for your time and help. One more thing . I see I have been using `angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"` as angular library. Should I just include lib for 2.0 in order to make it work?

Comment: First of all, check it it works with the latest angular 1.* generation (I think it's 1.5) - Angular 2 has many changes and I don't think this tutorial will work for that version

Comment: @AlonEitan ok..thnx a lot dude! :)